# MySQL date or PHP time?

Tags: php, mysql

I usually store dates as integers using PHP's `time()` function in a MySQL database rather than using MySQL's date format simply because it's easier to manipulate when I pull it back out, but are there any disadvantages to this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Range:**

There's always the obvious disadvantage: The range that you can store is limited från 1970 to 2038. If you need to store dates outside of this range, you'll generally need to use another format. The most common case I've found where this apply is to birthdates.

**Readability:**

I think that the most important reason that people chose to use one of the built-in date-types it that the data is easier to interpret. You can do a simple select, and understand the values without having to format the response further.

**Indexes:**

A good technical reason to use the date types is that it allows for indexed query in some cases that unix timestamps doesn't. Consider the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE year(mydate_field) = 2009;
```

If mydate_field is of a native date type, and there's an index on the field, this query will actually use an index, despite the function call. This is pretty much the only time that mysql can optimize function calls on fields like this. The corresponding query on a timestamp field won't be able to use indices:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE year(from_unixtime(mytimestamp_field)) = 2009;
```

If you think about it for a bit, there's a way around it, though. This query does the same thing, and *will* be able to use index optimizations:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE mytimestamp_field > unix_timestamp("2009-01-01") AND mytimestamp_field < unix_timestamp("2010-01-01");
```

**Calculations:**

Generally, I store dates as unix time, despite the disadvantages. This isn't really based on it's merits, but rather it's because I'm used to it. I've found that this simplifies some calculations, but complicate others. For example, it's very hard to add a month to a unix timestamp since the number of seconds per month varies. This is very easy using the mysql DATE_ADD() function. However, I think that in most cases it actually simplifies calculations. For example, it's quite common that you want to select the posts from, say, the last two days. If the field contains a unix timestamp this can be done easily by simply doing:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE mytimestamp_field > time() - 2*24*3600;
```

It's probably a matter of taste, but I personally find this faster and easier than having to rember the syntax of a function such as DATE_SUB().

**Timezones:**

Unix timestamps can't store time zone data. I live in sweden which has a single timezone, so this isn't really a problem for me. However, it can be a major pain if you live in a country that spans multiple timezones.

Comment: I just wanted to say "+1" for mentioning the UNIX_TIMESTAMP and the FROM_UNIXTIME functions... essentially giving you the best of both worlds.

Comment: Meant to come back and give you the check after I collected a few more answers.... thanks! This is a good answer.

Answer (score 9):

One disadvantage is that you won't be able to manipulate and query
those dates using SQL functions.

Answer (score 4):

I used to do the same, but now I store it as a MySQL DateTime - simply because that means when looking at the raw data in the database I can interpret it easily.

Other than that, it's possibly easier to work with the data with other languages that don't use the UNIX timestamp so heavily (as PHP does), but there isn't really a huge pull either way.

Answer (score 3):

UNIX timestamp has obvious limitations as to the range of dates that you're able to store.

I also always use `DATETIME` fields now.  You can do a lot of DATE math using SQL so you can pull out useful info like `DATEDIFF` between now and a stored date without using any PHP at all.

Answer (score 3):

You can define an auto-update clause for MySQL's timestamps in your table definition.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html

Answer (score 2):

There are many disadvantages:

- Lack of precision; Unix time is only accurate to the second, and only for dates between 1901-12-13 and 2038-01-19 when using the typical 32-bit integer
- You can't use any built-in database functions to query or manipulate the data
- You can't store a timezone

If you need a `time_t`, it's easy enough to convert to one in code.

Answer (score 1):

Only a couple I can think of:
* If another non-php application needs to use the database, this will be in a difficult format to read.
* If you want to do any SQL based work on these dates (e.g. adding a month or getting all values for a particular year, etc), this will be more difficult.

Comment: Pretty much all common languages have built-in support for epoch time.

Answer (score 1):

A slight loss of detail. The MySQL Datetime variable can be very precise.

Also, if you're gonna have to compare dates in your database, the date format has some built in functions you won't be able to use.

Comment: I'd like to see a reference for your claim that DATETIME is more precise.

Comment: You mean more precise the time() function? 1) http://be2.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php  and 2) http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html           Time() goes to second, MySQL DateTime goes to microseconds.

Answer (score 1):

I think that for scalability reasons it is better to use Unix time-stamps.

**Advantages**:

- Always stored in `UTC` timezone(if you have servers across multiple time-zones no conversion is needed).
- Applications convert them to the preferred timezone(This occurs only once, at last level possible).
- Not strings(those are huge in comparison with integers).
- Less database calculations(Stuff like `created` < 19345345345-24*60*60 is calculated once).

EDIT:
MySQL Timestamps are not stored internally as strings, but when pulled out of the database those are converted to strings. `DATETIME` type is not modified by `MySQL`, meaning that if you put a date in the database you get the same.

If you have visitors on a website from a different timezone you would have to convert dates like string->string instead of integer->string).
In some countries dates are not just numbers(For example in France it is Mardi 15 mai 2012 I prefer doing that in PHP or JS. I think that a simpe convertion integer->string is faster than Integer->String->String.
Plus no headache if migrating to servers in other country.

**Fake disadvantages**:

- I believe that the limited range of Unix time-stamps isn't actually limited. A time-stamp is an integer in the database, so you can adjust the size. By default an `unsigned` integer is `int(10)` meaning you can store numbers up to `4294967295`, but it's limits are not fixed so we can easily change <strike>`int(10)`</strike> `int` to <strike>`int(16)`</strike> `bigint`

Comment: I don't think they're actually stored as strings internally. And I don't see how how it does fewer DB calculations... `date_add(my_date, interval 2 months)` should only be calculated once as well, but could be done PHP-side anyway. Not sure about the timezone thing...do MySQL timestamps have the timezone embedded or is it global per database or something?

Comment: In MySQL those are stored as UTC and pulled out for the client timezone. From MySQL [Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html) " Values for TIMESTAMP columns are converted from the current time zone to UTC for storage, and from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval.".

Comment: Ok, I see your point now. I don't think the timezone would be an issue if you set MySQL to leave at as UTC if you want to convert it PHP-side, but the string->int->string optimization is a valid point, however I suspect it isn't a big cost. You're parsing what, maybe 100 dates on a page?

Comment: I prefer to do it this way just because I believe there are smaller chances to be wrong so no matter on what project I am working on it's done "the right way" or "my right way". I believe there is one good way of doing it, and if there is not and it's more task specific I would like to discover those specificities. About the cost of those type conversions I think that there is no cost in avoiding them.

Comment: I don't think there's any one "the right way" here. One solution is at best marginally better than the other, and neither is "wrong" or "bad practice". One disadvantage I discovered recently to unix timestamps is that MySQL's `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` doesn't seem to work on negative numbers (at least not without some hackery).

Answer (score 0):

That's not too bad but you'll be loosing some built in functionality such as:

select * from table1 where dateColumn = getDate()-30

Use datetime if you can!