# timestamp issue

Tags: php, mysql, insert, timestamp

I have some scripts and in the database table I have set the dato to int(25) and timestamp

I have a create topic script and then I create a topic it insert the date and time in the timestamp tabel (dato).

But somehow my comment script will not insert the time :S and its the same stuff I use :S.

Here is my script

```
    if(isset($_POST['opret_kommentar']))
{
 $indhold = $_POST['indhold'];
 $godkendt = "ja";

 $mysql = connect();
 $stmt = $mysql->prepare("INSERT INTO forum_kommentare (fk_forum_traad, brugernavn, indhold, dato, godkendt) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)") or die($mysql->error);
 $stmt->bind_param('issis', $traadID, $_SESSION['username'], $indhold, $dato, $godkendt) or die($mysql->error);
 $stmt->execute();
 $stmt->close();

 $svar = mysqli_insert_id($mysql); 

 header("location: forum.traad.php?traadID=$traadID&kategoriID=$kategoriID&#$svar");

}
```

Here is my create topic script so you can see its the same stuff I use :S

```
    if(isset($_POST['send'])) {

 $kategoriID = $_GET['kategoriID'];
    $overskrift = $_POST['overskrift'];
    $indhold    = $_POST['indhold'];
 $godkendt   = "ja";

    $mysql = connect();
    $stmt = $mysql->prepare("INSERT INTO forum_traad (overskrift, indhold, fk_forum_kategori, brugernavn, dato, godkendt) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)") or die($mysql->error);
 $stmt->bind_param('ssisis', $overskrift, $indhold, $kategoriID, $_SESSION['username'], $dato, $godkendt) or die($mysql->error);
 $stmt->execute();
 $stmt->close();

 $traadID = mysqli_insert_id($mysql);

  header("location: forum.traad.php?traadID=$traadID&kategoriID=$kategoriID");

}#Lukker isset send
```

Here is my SQL

> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `forum_kommentare` (   `id` int(11) NOT
>   NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   `fk_forum_traad` int(11) NOT NULL,
>   `brugernavn` text NOT NULL,   `indhold` mediumtext NOT NULL,   `dato`
>   timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE
>   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,   `godkendt` varchar(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'ja',
>   PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
>   AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
>
> --
>
> ### -- Data dump for tabellen `forum_kommentare`
>
> ---
>
> --
>
> ### -- Struktur-dump for tabellen `forum_traad`
>
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `forum_traad` (   `id` int(11) NOT NULL
>   AUTO_INCREMENT,   `overskrift` text NOT NULL,   `indhold` mediumtext
>   NOT NULL,   `fk_forum_kategori` int(11) NOT NULL,   `brugernavn` text
>   NOT NULL,   `dato` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON
>   UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,   `godkendt` varchar(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT
>   'ja',   PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
>   AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
>
> --
>   -- Data dump for tabellen `forum_traad`

Hope someone can help me :/

Answer (score 0):

Apart from your code that need's to be proper formated so one can read it I strongly suggest you go with the MySQL date field and not a timestamp.

So change this query to this:

```
// notice that the date is inserted by MySQL with the NOW() operator
$stmt = $mysql->prepare("INSERT INTO forum_traad (overskrift, indhold, fk_forum_kategori, brugernavn, dato, godkendt) VALUES (?,?,?,?,NOW(),?)") or die($mysql->error);
```

**Why should you use the MySQL date field instead of a timestamp?**

DATETIME's range...
'1000-01-01 00:00:00' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59'.

TIMESTAMP's range...
'1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07'

Not only that but you also have a lot of build-in MYSQL functions to work with DATETIME's like `INTERVAL` which will allow you to do great things.

```
// easy pull all comments values from within a range
SELECT * FROM your_table
WHERE your_date_field = DATE_SUB('2001-01-01 12:12:12' + INTERVAL 15 DAYS;
```

If you do need to work with timestamps on PHP you can pull them real time on SQL like this:

```
// converts a DATETIME field real time to timestamps
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(your_date_field)
FROM your_table (...)
And when you pull them out just format them anyway you like using strftime. Example bellow.

// pull a date from MySQL and format them to a custom format
// %A -> full weekday | %B -> full month name | %d -> month day | %Y - year 1999
$sql = "SELECT title, name, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) as timestamp
        FROM your_table
        WHERE your_limits";
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($sql));
echo strftime("%A, %B %d, %Y", $result['timestamp']);
```

I had already [covered a question in the same topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077827/how-to-display-date-and-price-in-a-mysql-database-and-display-it-in-various-forma/3077960#3077960) so you can look on that thread for aditional responses.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

A more cheap and cheerful solution would be...

```
$stmt = $mysql->prepare("INSERT INTO forum_traad (overskrift, indhold, fk_forum_kategori, brugernavn, godkendt) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)") or die($mysql->error);
```

Just don't set the dato column. The first (leftmost) `TIMESTAMP` column of any table will automatically be set to the current date time when a row is inserted or updated.